# Azure SDK Upgrade from 2.2 to 2.6

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

MS Build crashed once I upgraded Azure SDK from 2.2 to 2.6 SDK. I get the following error during MS build.... can anyone help me with what is an actual issue in 2.6

[Click here to enlarge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n38n.png)
[image]

Comment: As far as I know the issue is that if the package takes too long to generate, this occurs. As a workaround you can try using SDK 2.4, or possibly building the package somewhere with a faster CPU and I/O, which could bring build time under the bug limit.

Comment: Is SDK 2.6 installed on your build server?

Comment: There was an issue with cspack in SDK 2.5 but I think it should be fixed in SDK 2.6.

Comment: A lot of time has passed since you question, did you resolve the issue?